# Installing java on red hat enterpirse linux 3

Tags: linux, bash, java, eclipse, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to run eclipse IDE which results in an error which says no java virtual machine was found. The result of running "/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java" command is that it displays - one program which provides java that is "/usr/share/java/libgcj-java-placeholder.sh". I have deleted that file since then trying to add a new symbolic link but to new success. I have set the path in ~/.bash-profile and ~/.bashrc even then eclipse doesn't detect the jdk. Any suggestions on installing java will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to make sure that you have java installed which you can get [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) . Next you will want to add an environment variable JAVA_HOME which you can add to .bash_profile or .bashrc along with adding it to your path

> export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_39'
>
> export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$GRAILS_HOME/bin:$PATH

Then for eclipse you have to make sure it knows where java is. Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs click add and select the location of your jdk. Also look at Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler and make sure that JDK Compliance matches the JDK you've installed.

Comment: That's exactly what I have done before. But that didn't work at all.